# How to convert array type column in dataframe to string

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Spark Data Frame with a random number of columns. Some of these columns are `array<Int>` type. How should I find array columns in Data Frame and convert it to String?

For example, if the field is `[1, 2, 3]` (array of int), it should be converted to one string `{1, 2, 3}`.

The process:

```
  df.write
    .format("orc")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .saveAsTable(s"temp_table")
```

Comment: did you try `string(array)` or `array.cast("string")`?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the columns as string type. As to how to convert the array of integers to string :

```
val a = [1, 2, 3]
val b = a.map(x => x.toString).mkString(",")
```

b contains the value you want to write.

For the part on how to find what data type a given column contains, you can create an array of columns and a corresponding array of their data types.

```
val colName = df.columns
val colType = df.schema.fields.map(x=>x.dataType).map(x=>x.toString)
```

colType contains the data type the corresponding column contains. Note that you may have to write a simple parser to check the data types.

You may also remove the `map(x=>x.toString)` and then check for `i^{th}` column using

```
colType(i).isInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType]

//returns true for arrays
```

Comment: thank you for response. Could you help me find the array columns in spar data frame in stream.

Answer (score 0):

you can using mkstring on the array to convert into single string

```scala
val s=Array(1,2,3)
val str=s.mkString(",")
```

o/p:

```
str: String = 1,2,3
```

Comment: thank you for response. Could you help me write code which find the array columns in spar data frame.